# Set a field value within form __init__ function

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to find out an efficient way to set a field value within form **init** method. My models are similar to below

```
class Users(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField()
    lastname = models.CharField()

class profile(models.model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Users, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class logindetails(models.model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Users, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(profile, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    login_time = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

My form is like as below:

```
class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
            model = logindetails
            fields = [__all__]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._rowid = kwargs.pop('rowid', None)
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        instance = profile.objects.get(id=self._rowid)
        self.fields['user'] = instance.user  <--- Facing difficulties here
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Django had built-in ways of setting initial form values, the documentation is available here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values